# connecting to localhost Kafka pod

Tags: c#, kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am new to k8s, have installed Kafka to the local cluster using helm install command and it is installed successfully and shown it using

helm list

and using

Kubectl get all -A

Command as running.

I installed Confluent.Kafka nugget package in my C# project and try to connect to the pod but it is not connected using localhost:13090 and giving no error message

Please note that the namespace of the pod is “default” while the namespace of the application pod is “my-pod”

Please advise me, thank you

Comment: `localhost` is the pod itself, not another pod or the node the pod is running on.  The Kafka charts will include a Service to reach the broker pods, and you need to use the service's name as a host name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 90% of the answer included in your question, you mention that the namespace is different so that means you need to **add ".default" to your service name**.

You also mention a port that possibly used to connect from the outside cluster but inside the cluster, you can use **9092** with the service including the word headless.

Example

```
mykafka-service-headless.default:9092
```

or

```
mykafka-service-headless.default
```

without port as this is the default one.

**You will not need port forwarding** but just in case, you may execute the `port-forward` command for 9092 for the subject Kafka pods.